# How can I set a customized distance between child of flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
</div>

.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;    
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 140;
}


.a{
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 17px;
}

.b{
    //??
    height: 40px;
}

.c{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 18px;
}
```

I have three `<div>`s a, b and c in the container `<div>`. I want an element a to be positioned 10px to the top of the container, b to be positioned 50px to the top of the container and c to be positioned 10px to the bottom of the container.
How should I set b's style in order to achieve this? I want to avoid using absolute position if possible since when I tried to use it, somehow the width of b changed. I want to know if there is a way to set a customized distance between children of a flexbox.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish; can you show a picture o something to kinda explain what you expect to see?

Comment: but above b you have a?

Comment: Yes. a is above b and I update the height.

Comment: I can do it for you, Can you draw what you want for me?

Comment: [like this?](https://sketch.io/render/sk-39f80375bde11cfddf6f2c1eb77b7b8d.jpeg)

[Draw here](https://sketch.io/sketchpad/en/)

Comment: I added a picture on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easier that you adjust the distances here with *margins* - so you can remove `justify-content: space-between`.

Add `margin-top: 23px` to `b` and `margin-top: auto` to `c`. Check the below demo (you can inspect the *red lines* to verify that the distances are correct):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*justify-content: space-between;*/
  height: 140px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}
.a {
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 17px;
}
.b {
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 23px;  /* ADDED */
}
.c {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-top: auto; /* ADDED */
}

/* STYLING */
.a,.b,.c {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: cadetblue;
}
.a:before,.b:before,.c:before {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  width: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  background: red;
}
.a:before {
  height: 10px;
}
.b:before {
  height: 50px;
  left: 200px;
}
.c:before {
  left: 100px;
  top: unset;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I am looking for. I was trying to set margin for b but it still has some gap between a and b. Now I understand that I need to remove justify-content: space-between to customize my own distance.